# Git warning : url contains a newline in its path component & leads to error which : (Fatal: credential url cannot be parsed) Linux Mint 21 Vannesa

Tags: git, github, debian, linux-mint

This is my first time using linux, so i had to reinstall and configure all the tools i've been using. It's very challenging for me, and now i went to have an issue with git.

I already install git which my version is 2.34 using terminal, already set the global user.email & user.password. The commit part its fine, origin path already set from my repository in the github.com, but when i am try to push this will happen :

```
[2022-09-29T17:43:50.693Z] warning: url contains a newline in its path component: https://github.com/myusername/myownrepo.git
git push -u origin main

git remote add origin https://github.com/myusername/myownrepo.git/
fatal: credential url cannot be parsed: https://github.com/myusername/myownrepo.git.git
git push -u origin main
```

Already search for explanation & fixing but nothing works and clear enough for me.

Please help, i need this for my development & deployment

Comment: Can you check your `.git/config` file if it is valid? Remote URLs must not contain a new line